# How can I enable anonymous access to a Samba share under ADS security mode?

Tags: network-shares, samba, redhat-enterprise-linux, privacy

I'm trying to enable anonymous access to a single service in my Samba config. Authorized user access is working perfectly, but when I attempt a no-password connection, I get this message:

```
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[...] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba
3.3.8-0.51.el5] tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

The message log shows this error:

```
... smbd[21262]: [2010/05/24 21:26:39,  0] smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(1004)
... smbd[21262]:   Can't become connected user!
```

The smb.conf is configured thusly:

```
[global]
   security = ads
   obey pam restrictions = Yes
   winbind enum users = Yes
   winbind enum groups = Yes
   winbind use default domain = true
   valid users = "@domain admins", "@domain users"
   guest account = nobody
   map to guest = Bad User

[evilshare]
   path = /evil/share
   guest ok = yes
   read only = No
   browseable = No
```

Given that I have 'map to guest = Bad User' and 'guest ok' specified, I don't understand why it is trying to "become connected user". Should it not be trying to "become guest user"?

Comment: Which version of Samba are you using? Which type of Windows(?) client is trying to access your Samba?

Answer (score 1):

remove

> valid users = "@domain admins", "@domain users"

from [global], only use it in shares that are not "guest" enabled

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this tutorial](http://www.debuntu.org/guest-file-sharing-with-samba)

You remembered to restart samba to pull the config
also what are the local permissions for that folder?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the information from that link? It helps prevent link rot

Comment: that tutorial should not be used - "security = share" is deprecated, see my blog post : http://blog.realcomputerguy.com/2010/12/samba-and-guest-shares-with-security.html

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to set:

```
auth methods = guest sam winbind
restrict anonymous = 0
guest account = nobody
```

Of course, make sure the `nobody` user has been created without a password:

```
auth methods = guest sam winbind
```